# Arabs and other nationalities

Tags: quran, practical-islam, islamic-basis, jannah

Do Arabs stand a better chance in getting into Heaven as the Holy Quran is written in Arabic?

What i'm trying to ask is that, since they know Arabic and the Holy Quran is written in Arabic, isn't it easier for Arabs to understand and comprehend the Holy Quran compared to other nationalities?

Other nationalities may not understand due to the language difference.

If Arabs have the advantage, is it fair to say, punishments will be greater due to their greater capacity to understand the Holy Quran?

Comment: Interesting question, I am an Arab, yet I find those converts and non-Arab more serious about understanding Islam than Arabs.

Comment: Yes, I do agree converts and non-arabs are more serious. Being a non arab, somehow i feel I do not grasp the exact meaning even its translated into English.

Comment: Inshallah, it will be easy for you to understand it. There are some verses that are context-based or need exegesis to get the meaning of it.

Comment: Amin. May Allah ease our paths.

Comment: I feel that Allah's Pleasure on His servant is concomitant with his or her efforts. So if you (as a non-Arab) find it difficult to read and understand the Qur'an vis-a-vis an Arab who can do so flawlessly, I guess you may have a better chance of pleasing Allah, insha Allah. And Allah knows best.

Comment: Yet another flip side to this question is that a native Arab will find it harder to answer Allah when he is asked about (or lack thereof) his adherence to the Book, since he has no excuse of not being able to read and understand the Qur'an.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @Najeeb,I believe so too. I am unable to find a authentic hadith to supplement yours and my thoughts. Well, pen down your reply as an answer so that i can mark it :)

Comment: @Newbie, added and done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ponder upon the following for your answer (inshAllah)-

**Surat al hujarat- 49/13**

> "O mankind, We have created you from a male and a female and have made you into nations and tribes for you to know one another.  Truly, the noblest of you with Allah  is the most pious. Truly, Allah is All-Knowing, All-Aware."

**Surat al-qamar- 54/17**

> "And We have certainly made the Qur'an easy for remembrance, so is there any who will remember?"

**Surat al-baqara- 2/286**

> "Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned. "Our Lord, do not impose blame upon us if we have forgotten or erred. Our Lord, and lay not upon us a burden like that which You laid upon those before us. Our Lord, and burden us not with that which we have no ability to bear. And pardon us; and forgive us; and have mercy upon us. You are our protector, so give us victory over the disbelieving people."

Narrated in Musnad ahmad ibn Hanbal, the prophet Muhammad, peace be upon him said-

> "O people!  Your God is one and your forefather (Adam) is one.  An Arab is not better than a non-Arab and a non-Arab is not better than an Arab, and a red (i.e. white tinged with red) person is not better than a black person and a black person is not better than a red person, except in piety."

Yes, arabic speakers have an advantage, so learn arabic ! There is nothing stopping you as there are a plethora of ways to do that these days. Many of the shuyoukh/sheikhs are from non arab backgrounds, yet to fully understand the quran they all learned the quranic arabic. It is sort of like telling an english guy to go read some shakespear: it would be best for him to learn the shakespearean prose first before hand, so as to gain as much from it as possible, due to meanings lost in translation. We have many a dedicated scholars today in the tasfeer ul quran alhamdilullah. I implore a site for learning islamic studies for free created by Dr Bilal Phillips of Jamaica.

http://www.islamiconlineuniversity.com/

May Allah make it easy on you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @Jam! Amazing citation of Hadith. Love the way you structure your share. Simple and straightforward! +1

Comment: Hey, thanks for that brother! This is probably the first time I havent recieved an onslaught of downvotes lol. I actually came here again to make a comment to you about your question. You see, I have pondered upon the question some more and I have come to the conclusion that a non arab is at no disadvantage but rather it is a mercy from Allah! (now hold up this isnt an insult to arabs)Allah is giving us more opportunities to attain good deeds. 
Read the following hadith in my next comment

Comment: Jabir (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: There were some plots of land lying vacant around the mosque. The people of Banu Salamah decided to move to this land and come nearer to the mosque. The Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) heard about it and said to them, "I have heard that you intend to move near the mosque.'' They said: "Yes, O Messenger of Allah! We have decided to do that.''

Comment: Thereupon the Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) said, "O Banu Salamah! Stay in your houses, because your footprints (when you come to the mosque) will be recorded.'' He said this twice. They said: "We would not have liked it, had we moved near the mosque.''
[Muslim].

Comment: You might ask, what relevance does this hadith have to our discussion? Well, in having the people of banu salamah stay where they originally were is giving them many more chances and opportunities to gain rewards and ajr (because in the following hadith...

Comment: Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) said, "He who goes to the mosque in the morning or in the evening, Allah prepares for him a place in Jannah whenever he goes to the mosque in the morning and returns from it in the evening.''
[Al-Bukhari and Muslim].)

So basically, in conclusion, this is a mercy from Allah and also a test of your imaan, just like banu salamah were originally from this land far away from the mosque through nofault of their own,Muhammad(SAW) saw it as a mercy from Allah to these people.

Comment: Allah knows best and Allah knows what is best for us. I also live far away from my "local" masjid all my life and got annoyed alot, but reading that hadith made me realise the impotance of this ayah **Surah Alanfal 8/30** 
Although they plan, Allah plans and Allah is the best of planners

Subhan'Allah. Praise be to the creator. 
So take this as a mercy and take this opportunity to struggle and learn arabic in the cause of Allah so you can fully understand the verbatim word of God in the intended language, that you can be rewarded inshaAllah.

Answer (score 3):

Every Muslim has a duty to learn about their deen and so it doesnt matter if you are Arab or not you will still have the same punishment. Also the arabic used in the Qur'an is very poetic and harder to understand than Fusha Arabic (most Arabs dont even speak formal Arabic so even Fusha is hard for them). And you can find the translation of the Qur'an in different languages anywhere you go.
The answer: everyone will be judged according to their deeds and

Comment: Thank you for sharing @Aisha, I do understand translation are everywhere. But different Imams have different interpretations which makes it hard to comprehend. I'm referring to the deep meanings of a Ayat in the Holy Quran.

Comment: As I said before, the deep Ayat are even hard for most Arabs to understand. And don't forget Allah is a fair judge so he will look at how capable you are at understanding the deen. The most important thing is for you to try because Allah loves the one who tries to get closer to him no matter how little the deed. Also the one struggling gets more deeds.

Comment: Well done @Aisha, I really admire your admirable and logical response. especially as you correctly pointed out: the arabic used in the Qur'an is very... harder to understand than Fusha Arabic (most Arabs dont even speak formal Arabic so even Fusha is hard for them).

Answer (score 2):

As we know , Allah is impartial , so when someone **Cant** understand something from Holy Qur'an , so Allah doesn't want it from him/her .
when you **cant** understand something from Qur'an or you don't know a rule , it's OK to do it and god knows that . but you **have to** try to understand it , but if you couldn't , it's OK .
**P.S** : I think holy Qur'an has been translated in most of languages .

Comment: Thank you for sharing @ShaPesar. Even with translation there are many variations. Which is authentic, and exact to the Holy Quran in Arabic, is something baffling.

Comment: @Newbie , As I Said , You Have to Try to Find out the real answer , but if you couldn't , it' OK .

Answer (score 2):

@Newbie, Allah's Pleasure on His servants is concomitant with their efforts. So if you (as a non-Arab) find it difficult to read and understand the Qur'an vis-a-vis an Arab who can do so flawlessly, I guess you may have a better chance of pleasing Allah, insha Allah.

Yet another aspect of this question is that a native Arab will find it harder to answer to Allah when he or she is asked about (or lack thereof) their adherence to the Book, since they had no excuse of not being able to read and understand the Qur'an.

Ultimately, it's efforts that are counted with Allah. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

As a revert I must agree with Ghasn. I think the answer is no as all Muslims have a obligation to lean about the Deen especially, it is the one of the most important requirements of any Muslim to acquire "ieelm" (knowledge) of the Deen and the Duniya.

It is said something to this effect that who ever reads a single letter of the Quraan even with out knowing its meaning receives the same blessing and reward as those who know what it means.

There is a hadith something to this effect : Qula Rarululahi SAllahu Alayhi wa selem inna'maal a'umalu binniyati - The Prophet Muhammad (SAW) said verily actions are based upon their intentions.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @Reign. Interesting. Could you quote your Hadith. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Allah said in the Holy Quran in the latest Aya in the Al-Baqara Sura that He wasn't to order somebody to do what they cannot do. Thus, Muslim must do the best of what he can do to learn about obligations and prohibitions but if he could not, Allah will treat him only according to what he could do, as Allah is the Merciful, *And Allah knows best*.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @عمروخضير. In Sha Allah, somethings are just not meant for human brain to ponder and worry about. Do the best we can, and Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

I've started watching 'Arabic with Husna' by Nouman Ali Khan on Bayyinah.tv and in the very first lesson he teaches us to memorise and internalise, 'walaqad yassarnal qur'ana lithikri' - "And indeed we have made the Qur’an easy to learn and easy to remember". Allah doesn't say "...easy to learn and easy to remember **for Arabs**" - think about it insh'Allah.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @user1593993! Indeed, the Holy Quran is easy to learn and easy to remember.